# How to display center image in gallery display in imageview if user scrolling in gallery in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I have an image view and gallery on screen. In gallery I have a lot of images. If the user scrolls in the gallery, I need to display gallery center image should be displayed in image view.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: set ScaleType of imageview as FIT_CENTER

Answer (score 0):

This assuming the image view that needs to be updated is stored in a field called mImageView, and that the views in the gallery are ImageViews

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)v).getDrawable());
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to to display gallery center image in image view on every scroll

Comment: The onitemselected method gets called every time the center image changes, even during a scroll.

Comment: @saarraz1 but he dont want to set image on click of item gallery.

Comment: @saarraz1 can u tell where we are getting the gallery center posistion image?

Comment: @Android Coader, The onItemSelected method gets called when a view in the gallery gets to the center of the gallery, not when it is clicked (that's onItemClickListener).

Comment: @mohan When the onItemSelected method gets called, the v parameter is the view in the center position. If you cast this parameter to ImageView, you get the image at the center position.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **`OnItemSelectedListener`** for your gallery. you have to implement your logic inside **`onItemSelected`** function

```
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```